# Recieving 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location storing new pointer in pointer array

Tags: c++, pointers, graphics, logic, sfml

I am writing a basic `Asteroids` program, using the `SFML graphics library`, and am receiving `errors/crashes` when debugging the program. This happens only when I am attempting to fire a `"photon torpedo"` out of my ship, via the spacebar. Here is a snippet of the code.

```
//check for keypress

        if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Space) {
            for (int index = 0; index < MAX_PHOTONS; index++) {
                photons[index] = new SpaceObject(PHOTON_TORPEDO, PHOTON_RADIUS, ship->getLocation(), ship->getVelocity(), ship->getAngle())
                photons[index]->applyThrust(PHOTON_SPEED);
                std::cout << "LAUNCHING TORPEDO\n";
            }
        }

    // update game objects ------------------------------------------
     ship->updatePosition();

     for (int index = 0; index < ARRAY_SIZE; index++) {
         if (&asteroids[index] != NULL) {
             asteroids[index]->updatePosition();
         }
     }

     for (int index = 0; index < MAX_PHOTONS; index++) {
         if (&photons[index] != NULL) {
             photons[index]->updatePosition();
         }
     }


    // draw new frame ------------------------------------------------
    window.clear();
    window.draw(background);

    for (int index = 0; index < ARRAY_SIZE; index++) {
        if (&asteroids[index] != NULL) {
            asteroids[index]->draw(window);
        }
    }

    for (int index = 0; index < MAX_PHOTONS; index++) {
        if (&photons[index] != NULL) {
            photons[index]->draw(window);
        }
    }
```

Running the code causes an instant crash, and debugging results in:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00311746 in polygons2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access
>   violation reading location 0x00000018.

I believe the error lies in the keypress event.

Comment: If it causes an instant crash, you have a *ripe* candidate for a *debugger*. That access violation strongly suggests you're dereferencing a NULL pointer to some structure, specifically something 24 bytes deep on that structure. Use a debugger, and you'll find your problem. And FYI, this: `if (&asteroids[index] == NULL)` makes no sense at all. That ampersand shouldn't be there. That mistake is repeated in multiple places in this code.

Comment: `&photons[index] != NULL` is always true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code has typos. Don't use reference operator access object references. Elements of asteroids & photons are addresses of corresponding objects.

```
 for (int index = 0; index < ARRAY_SIZE; index++) {
     if (asteroids[index] != NULL) {
         asteroids[index]->updatePosition();
     }
 }

 for (int index = 0; index < MAX_PHOTONS; index++) {
     if (photons[index] != NULL) {
         photons[index]->updatePosition();
     }
 }


// draw new frame ------------------------------------------------
window.clear();
window.draw(background);

for (int index = 0; index < ARRAY_SIZE; index++) {
    if (asteroids[index] != NULL) {
        asteroids[index]->draw(window);
    }
}

for (int index = 0; index < MAX_PHOTONS; index++) {
    if (photons[index] != NULL) {
        photons[index]->draw(window);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for clarification of the correct answer of Dmitry Kolchev:

A `&` as you use it in your code retrieves the address of an entity:

```
int i = 15;   /* Integer, contains '15' */
int* pi = &i;  /* Pointer to an integer, contains the address of i in memory*/
```

Now you have an array like

```
int array [3] = {1, 2, 3};
```

Then

```
assert(1 == array[0]);
assert(2 == array[1]);
assert(3 == array[3]);
```

holds. 
`array[i]` retrieves the content of the array at position `i`.
`&array[i]` denotes the memory address of the element at position `i`:

```
int a0 = array[0];   /* array[0] is of type int */
int* ap0 = &array[0]; /* &array[0] is of type int* */
```

By the way, `array[i]` is just short hand for `*(array + i)` and `&array[0]` equals `array + i`:

```
assert(array[i] == *(array + i));
assert(&array[i] == array + i);
```

But that's a slightly different story...